# Use Case Scenario Template

Tags: uml, use-case

Where can I find some free use case scenario templates?

Thanks

PS. I know they're easy to find on google but I asked the question so the best ones could rise to the top.

Comment: Do not Google for Use Case scenario templates.  They were all deleted.  It's some kind of conspiracy.

Comment: Please define "best".  What do you mean by "best"?

Comment: @S.Lott: Haha, it would seem so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search revealed:

[Use Case Scenario Templates](http://www.scenarioplus.org.uk/download_uc_templates.html)

More can be found [here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Use+case+Scenario+Templates)

Answer (score 1):

The basic use case template should be:

1.Use case name
2.Purpose
3.Primary Actor
4.Secondary actor
5.Trigger.
6.Pre-Condition
7.Flow of event.
8.Post condition.
9.special requirement
10.priority
11.Sub use case.
12. Audit trail
13 Security.

Answer (score 0):

This wikipedia article has links to some templates. (At the bottom under external links).
[See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case#Use_case_templates)

Please read the first paragraph of the Use Case Template section though.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this book useful:

[writing effecitve use case](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201702258)